# Laravel 5's route helper doesn't work on fresh install

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am following [a tutorial](https://openclassrooms.com/courses/decouvrez-le-framework-php-laravel/) sayings that Laravel has a helper that permits to write the routes like that :

```
<?php 
get('/', function () {
return view('welcome');
});
```

Instead of :

```
<?php
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

(The "Route::" prefix is missing in the first one).

Since what i've looked the documentation (where I've found nothing really related but the providers involved), I correctly have in my providers :

```
'providers' => [

        /*
         * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
         */
        (...)
        Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider::class,
        (...)
        /*
         * Application Service Providers...
         */
        (...)
        App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,
        (...)

    ],
```

And the tutorial says that it has to work in a fresh install.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The router helper functions were removed in December. You can see the changes here:

https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/62cbae78ba2d40944892c5a16f2d2463087bce23

In the upgrade guide, you can see what is deprecated and removed.

> The `get`, `post`, and other route helper functions have been removed. You may use the `Route` facade instead.

Source: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/upgrade